# Generic list modify value of property in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, generics

Lets say i have following class

```
public class abc
{
    int id;
    string name;
}
```

i am using this class as a collection of some data and my business logic appends some rows in it.

```
List<abc> lstData = GetData();
```

Now if i have to modify some property value lets say i want to modify the name property with some value.

```
string replaceName = 'jay';
```

so this jay should be in every row of the list in name property.

how to do this ? i think there is a convertAll method can we use that....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ConvertAll` is usually used to create a new *list*, whereas it sounds like you just want to modify properties within existing objects. So I'd use:

```
foreach (abc value in lstData)
{
    value.name = replaceName;
}
```

(This code would look more idiomatic if you'd used names following the [.NET naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx), by the way.)

Alternatively, you could use `ConvertAll` if you wanted to create *new* objects:

```
List<abc> newList = lstData.ConvertAll(old => new abc { 
    id = old.id,
    name = replaceName
});
```

That's using a lambda expression for the delegate, and an object initializer to set the properties in each new object. The exact way that you'd approach this would depend on your real class.

Comment: what i want is the rest of the properties of list should not be changed only particular property of the list should be changed in all the rows. in this case name should be changed with any thing but ids should remain same. can it be achieved.

Comment: @ankur: Well have you tried the first piece of code? That just modifies a single property of all the objects in the list.

Comment: i have tried to do some think like this  int k = 1234;
            List<getData> lst = new List<getData>();
            getData g = new getData();
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                g.i = i;
                g.name = "ank " + i.ToString();
                lst.Add(g);
            }
            string b = "Rahul";
            lst.ConvertAll(s => s.name = b); and it is doing the thing.

Comment: @ankur: But that's not what my answer suggested, is it? Have you tried either of the approaches in my answer?

Comment: i tried both of them. i want to reuse the list after modifying it . i have used your second approach but not have created a new list for same.just iterated the list and changed the values.

Comment: @ankur: But that *has* created a new list - that's what `ConvertAll` does. If you don't *want* to create a new list, it would be better to use the first form, as then your code makes it more obvious what's going on. I'd normally expect a `ConvertAll` call to leave the original list intact (i.e. not modify the objects within it).

Answer (score 2):

Use [List.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx)

```
lstData.ForEach(x => x.name = "jay");
```

Comment: Personally I prefer using `foreach` unless there's a good reason to use `ForEach` (e.g. I've already *got* a delegate). See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx

Comment: @Jon I have a mostly C++ background :) Never used std::for_each because C++ didn't have lambdas. So you can imagine !! BTW reading your book **C# in depth** .. its amazing. The first programming book I picked up that didn't teach me how to do a for / while loop ...at least not yet

Comment: Glad you're enjoying it - I very deliberately wanted to write a book which *didn't* start off assuming no knowledge :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below LINQ operator ForEach():

```
lstData.ForEach(data => data.Name = replaceName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to assign the same value to a property of all the object in the list? If yes then you loop over it:

```
foreach (var item in lstData)
{
    item.name = "jay";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in real life, when you want to modify `Name`, you must be having Id, so based on that you can find a single object to be modified in the list like:

```
 abc objAbc =(
    from emp 
    in lstData 
    where emp => emp.Id = someId 
    select emp)
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Once you have `objAbc you can do objAbc.Name = "New Name"`

I hope that's what you want to know. you need to do using System.Linq in order to use linq-to-object.

Happy coding